# Can Vitamio Android Demo expire?

Tags: android, google-play, vitamio

I put the latest Vitamio Android Demo lib for video streaming in my app and I want to publish it on Google Play, but I am concerned whether or not it can expire after certain trial period. As far as I researched didn't find anyone complaining about it. Does anyone know if it's possible that this demo version expires after some time and doesn't let video streaming work anymore?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well basically I'm interested if this Demo version of Vitamio lib would stop working after some time being used in my app (published on Google Play)? Or it would just keep working normally no matter it's just a demo version?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Vitamin in one of my PlayMarket apps. You can use it as long as you want, if you don't break Vitamio license rules:

- Everyone except individual needs to buy the Vitamio license, such as: government agency, education,institution, association, enterprise etc.

See for more details: https://www.vitamio.org/en/License/